# How has japanese writing changed in the last century?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, kanji, syntax

This is a fairly vague question and I will try and make it more specific, but, if possible, could you list the changes that have occured in japanese writing in particular? (e.g character change, sentence structure, way of writing, etc.). I don't expect there to be a complete list, but if you have anything that you know of please put it below. 
      I ask this because people say that some of my grandma's japanese, -particularly in letters-  is seldom used anymore, but is still largely understandable; so, I am curious as to what made it seem outdated. If it helps at all, my grandmother was born in Shimane prefecture in the mid 1930's

```
  Thank you!
          Morella A.
```

Comment: Why don't you make it more specific _before_ posting it?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Many times I may make some questions more specific after I post them because people may ask certain follow up questions that I didn't think would help, or I someone may ask something that I didn't think about.

Answer (score 4):

A lot has changed, IMO one good way is to compare newspapers from the days. This one is from the Meiji era: http://www.geocities.jp/tanaka_kunitaka/takeshima/saninshimbun/02.gif

This one from during WW2: http://userdisk.webry.biglobe.ne.jp/005/523/32/N000/000/000/123528635262516412541.jpg

This is from 1960: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-PAoTj0oNAQ0/U3XNJ1s7WpI/AAAAAAAAAAA/o2JBaQG5iaM/s1600/19601215_KobNP_1.jpg